# php shell_exec() function not working when the php page is deployed on to the internet

Tags: javascript, php, function, shell, cmd

I have created a very basic php page, which contains the following codes:

```php
<?php
$out = shell_exec('ipconfig');
echo $out
?>
```

This code successfully prints my ip-addresses on the web page. But when this page is made live on the internet using any hosting platforms, it prints nothing on the web page and the value of the variable out(`$out`) is also null.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: I'd say this behaviour is to be expected. Why would you want details of your server's network configuration available on a web page to anyone who wants to look?

Comment: True. But even if i write any other command such as "start calc",which opens a calculator, are not working.

Answer (score -1):

It return ip on Shell which will always return null on Server.

To Get ip on server :

Server IP
You can get the server IP address from $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'].

Client IP address

You can get the client IP from $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']

```
$ipAddress=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$macAddr=false;

#run the external command, break output into lines
$arp=`arp -a $ipAddress`;
$lines=explode("\n", $arp);

#look for the output line describing our IP address
foreach($lines as $line)
{
   $cols=preg_split('/\s+/', trim($line));
   if ($cols[0]==$ipAddress)
   {
       $macAddr=$cols[1];
   }
}
```

if you just want to dump it's result straight to the user you can cut to the chase and use passthru():

```
$cmd = shell_exec('ipconfig');
echo '<pre>';
passthru($cmd);
echo '</pre>';
```

If you want to display the output at run time as the program goes, you can do this:

```
while (@ ob_end_flush()); // end all output buffers if any

$proc = popen($cmd, 'r');
echo '<pre>';
while (!feof($proc))
{
    echo fread($proc, 4096);
    @ flush();
}
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: how to run shell commands after getting the IP address of the client?